# Adding local users to a group of servers

Tags: powershell-3.0

Got what maybe a unique problem here.  I have a bunch of servers that I need to add new local user accounts to.

I thought i had found my answer with the following command:

```
# Create new local Admin user for script purposes
$date = Get-Date -Format yyyy-MM-dd
$servers = get-content serverlist.txt

$username = read-host -Prompt "Enter Username"
$securepass = read-host -Prompt "Enter Password" -AsSecureString

foreach ($server in $servers)
{
    Invoke-command -ComputerName $server
    {
        $Computer = [ADSI]"WinNT://localhost"
        $LocalAdmin = $Computer.Create("User", "$username")
        $LocalAdmin.SetPassword("$securepass")
        $LocalAdmin.UserFlags = 64 + 65536 # ADS_UF_PASSWD_CANT_CHANGE + ADS_UF_DONT_EXPIRE_PASSWD
        $LocalAdmin.SetInfo()
    }
}
```

However when I run this code I get a few different errors.  It appears that the problem is with the "$Computer.Create("User"," section of the code.

I've actually paired this down to a simple basic local account creation script, and this version works:

```
invoke-command -computername <server> {[ADSI]$server="WinNT://localhost";$HD=$server.Create("User","TESTUSER");$HD.SetPassword("PASSWORD");$HD.SetInfo()}
```

Now that version works without a problem because its able to set the user and create the password using the quoted text.  So I moved on to setup variables with prompts to provide us a way to automate the process of new user creation.

So I moved on to this more automated version:

```
$date = Get-Date -Format yyyy-MM-dd
$username = read-host -Prompt "Enter Username"
$securepass = read-host -Prompt "Enter Password"
$server1 = "SERVER"
Invoke-command -computername $server1 {
        [ADSI]$server=("WinNT://localhost/")
        $HD=$server.Create("User",$username)        
        $HD.SetPassword($securepass)
        $HD.SetInfo()
        }
```

This however doesn't work and generates the following problem:

> The following exception occurred while retrieving member "Create": "Unknown error (0x80005000)"
>      + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], ExtendedTypeSystemException
>      + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CatchFromBaseGetMember
>      + PSComputerName        : SERVER
>
> You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
>      + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (SetPassword:String) [], RuntimeException
>      + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
>      + PSComputerName        : SERVER
>
> You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
>      + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (SetInfo:String) [], RuntimeException
>      + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
>      + PSComputerName        : SERVER

I"m actually not sure what is going wrong here.  The create method seems to be accepted in MULTIPLE other scripts, but for this one the moment I put that variable into the create method, it blows up.

Anybody know whats going wrong?  I'm getting ridiculously frustrated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to understand, that whenever you Invoke-Command, you don't have access to local variables (such as `$username`).

There are two ways to solve it in PowerShell v3.

Easier, with `$using:` prefix:

```
$username = 'foo'
Invoke-Command -ComputerName Test { $using:username }
```

More complicated, but works also on v2, with `param()` block and `-ArgumentList` parameter:

```
$username = 'foo'
Invoke-Command -ComputerName Test -ArgumentList $username {
    param ($user)
    $user
}
```

Comment: Argh, I figured this might be the problem, but I thought for sure with newer versions of powershell it was just fine.   Thank you so much Bartek, I'll give this a try and see if I can resolve it.   I'll update tomorrow.

Comment: Apologies for the delay in response. I've verified that you were exactly right it needed to have a Parameter added tot he invoke command, and then encapsulate with the argument list.   I have verified a new error and that is with the secure password ($securepass) variable, which is not passing a proper string to the invoke command.  I suspect there is an issue with this due to the hand-off between systems.